# Flutter Get.toNamed() argument is null

Tags: flutter, controller, arguments, flutter-getx

I've made nested navigation with GetX.

When I move to page with `Get.toNamed()`, the argument is null in the next controller. But when I move with `Get.to()`, the argument passed normally.

`MainPage.dart`

```
Widget getBody() {
  return GetBuilder<MainController>(
    builder: (_) => IndexedStack(
      index: _.pageIdx,
      children: [
        TravelMatePage(),
        AIAdvisorPage(),
        Navigator(
          key: Get.nestedKey(2),
          initialRoute: '/plans',
          onGenerateRoute: (settings) {
            switch(settings.name) {
              case '/plans': return GetPageRoute(page: () => PlansPage());
              case '/myPlanDetail': return GetPageRoute(page: () => MyPlanDetailPage());
            }
          },
        ),
        NotificationsPage(),
        SettingsPage()
      ],
  ));
}
```

`MyPlansController.dart`

```
void goToMyPlanDetailPage(String planId) {
  Get.toNamed('/myPlanDetail', id: 2, arguments: planId);
}
```

`MyPlanDetailController.dart`

```
@override
onInit() async {
  //The argument is null...
  final planId = Get.arguments as String;
  planData = await firestore.getMyPlanDetailData(planId);
}
```

Comment: I think, its a bug of GetX. Checkout this thread: https://github.com/jonataslaw/getx/issues/676

Comment: You can try adding `routeName` inside `GetPageRoute`.

Comment: @ZakariaHossain  I think so too!  GetX 5.0.0 version will be released soon. I hope that this bug will be fixed

Comment: @CavinMacwan  It is still null   :(

Answer (score 0):

```
case '/myPlanDetail': return GetPageRoute(page: () => MyPlanDetailPage(), settings: RouteSettings(name: settings.name, arguments: String),);
```

so here it is expecting a string type argument.